# Combinations of letters

Tags: math, combinations

Sorry for bad English, it's translation.

> How many ways can be chosen from the letters "abcde" set of 1, 2, 2 letters simultaneously?

Believing my calculation, the answer is 30. But I'm not sure...

Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on Math.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is equivalent to simultaneous drawing of 2 pairs of letters, which is equivalent to the number of serialized drawings of pairs of letters modulo number of serializations.

thus you have `(5 choose 2) . (3 choose 2) / 2 = 10 * 3 / 2 = 15`.

specifically,

```
a-bc-de    b-ac-de    c-ab-de    d-ab-ce    e-ab-cd
a-bd-ce    b-ad-ce    c-ad-be    d-ac-be    e-ac-bd
a-be-cd    b-ae-cd    c-ae-bd    d-ae-bc    e-ad-bc
```

another way to see this is to conceptualize your problem as assigning 5 distinguishable items to 5 positions organized in 3 slots with the slots being distinguished by their number of positions only and the positions within a slot being equivalent: `5! / (2! * 2! * 2!)`.

Comment: Thanks! My mistake was that I've did it in a such way: C(1,5)*C(2,4)*C(2,2), where C(m,n) is a combination of m on n